# Objects stacking on-top of eachother

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a project building a kanban board. While trying to integrate the kanban board rows with drag and drop with my current front-end design I encounter the problem of the drag and drop boxes stacking on top of eachother.

I have tried to put the boards into a row without it helping

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/mictho18/pen/wbxQGE

I want the to do, doing and done to spread over the side.

Comment: Well that answered my whole question. I had forgotten to grab the .JS file from github. Sry for wasting your time, haha

Comment: Each board column has `position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0` so they are all rendered in the same place.